# Unrecognized selector sent to instance?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit

How to fix such an error:
unrecognized selector sent to instance ?

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D userCoordinate = userLocation.location.coordinate;
CGFloat latDelta = rand()*.035/RAND_MAX -.02;
CGFloat longDelta = rand()*.03/RAND_MAX -.015;
CLLocationCoordinate2D newCoord = { userCoordinate.latitude + latDelta, userCoordinate.longitude + longDelta };
myPoint *mp = [[myPoint alloc] initWithCoordinate:newCoord title:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Vitaliy Home %d",i] subTitle:@"Home Sweet Home"];
[mv addAnnotation:mp]; //mv - (MKMapView *)mv
```

Error is on line :

```
myPoint *mp = [[myPoint alloc] initWithCoordinate:newCoord title:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Vitaliy Home %d",i] subTitle:@"Home Sweet Home"];
```

class myPoint:

```
@interface myPoint : NSObject<MKAnnotation> {
    NSString *title;
    NSString *subTitle;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
}

@property (nonatomic,readonly) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
@property (nonatomic,copy) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic,copy) NSString *subTitle;

- (id)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D) c title:(NSString *) t subTitle:(NSString *) st;

@end
```

Thank you.

Comment: is this method implemented?

Comment: @BrunoKoga it wasn't. I tried with implementation, the same result.

Comment: Quote the ENTIRE MESSAGE.  It will (most likely) tell you exactly what you're doing wrong if you read it carefully.

Comment: Incidentally, standard C++/Objective-C convention is to use initial capitals for class names.

Comment: @HotLicks I copied it to the question, have a look please..

Comment: Another problem you might have later is that the `subTitle` property should be `subtitle` per the MKAnnotation protocol.

Comment: Not clear why you edited the error message in and then out again, but it is `[myPoint setCoordinate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`.  This means that there is no "setCoordinate" method defined by your class "myPoint".

Comment: And there is no implicitly-defined "setCoordinate" method because "coordinate" is read-only.

Comment: .... and `myPoint` should be `MyPoint`.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably doing something like this in the `initWithCoordinate:...` method:

```
self.coordinate = c;
```

This is not a simple assignment, this is calling a method (property setter `setCoordinate:`) which is not there and it ends in exception.

**Fix compiler warnings!**

Comment: Yes, now i see, without 'self' it's okay.

Comment: yup red octagons are bad, and so are yellow triangles, fixing those does a lot of magic toward making a happy process.

Comment: @ProkopchukVitaliy Do you understand *why* using `self.coordinate = ...` doesn't work and using `coordinate = ...` does?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in not correct implementation of the method, thanks @BrunoKoga.