# [NSManagedObject setSwitchState:]: unrecognized selector sent in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

after checking all the answers of "**Unrecognised selector sent**" questions such as [unrecognized selector sent to instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6332630/unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance), and [Unrecognized selector sent to instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16843675/unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance) did not satisfy my situation so for that here is my full scenario:

**Description:**

in my app there exist a settings View which contain a **UISwitch** either to add all his reservation to the phone calendar or not.

so I need to save the choice of the user inside **CoreData**  to add reservations to calendar or not i.e the state of the **UISwitch**.

initially when the app start for the first time the **UISwitch**  will be **ON** and his state will be saved inside the **CoreData** with fixed ID 1 because I don`t want to add many Objects I need to keep only one object and when the user change the value of the **UISwitch** the app should update the object with new state I try this solution [How to update existing object in Core Data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10571786/how-to-update-existing-object-in-core-data) also I got an error

**Full Code:**

SwitchStateEntity.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
@interface switchState : NSManagedObject
@property(strong,nonatomic) NSNumber *switchId;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSNumber *switchState;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSNumber *showReminderAlert;
@end
```

SwitchStateEntity.m

```
#import "switchState.h"
@implementation switchState
@dynamic switchId;
@dynamic   switchState;
@dynamic showReminderAlert;
@end
```

SettingsViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MakeReservationViewController.h"
@interface SettingsViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *isAdedToCalendarOrNot;
@property (nonatomic) Boolean isSwitchOnOrOf;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *savedEventId;
@end
```

SettingsViewController.m

```
- (IBAction)DoneButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    // check the state of the switch //
    // save this state //

    NSError *error;
    CoreData *coreDataStack = [CoreData defaultStack];
    NSArray *fetchedObjects;
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest;
    NSEntityDescription *entity;
    // setting up the variable needed //
    fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"SwitchState" inManagedObjectContext:coreDataStack.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"remindMeSwitchId== %d", 1]];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    fetchedObjects = [coreDataStack.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    NSLog(@"%@",fetchedObjects);

    for( NSEntityDescription *name in fetchedObjects)
    {
        NSLog(@"Switch Id is: %@",[name valueForKey:@"remindMeSwitchId"]);
        NSLog(@"Switch State is: %@",[name valueForKey:@"remindMeSwitchState"]);
        SwitchStateEntity *h  = [ fetchedObjects firstObject];
        [h setSwitchState:[NSNumber numberWithBool:self.isSwitchOnOrOf]];
        // after this statement i go into Unrecognised selector had been sent//  
        [coreDataStack saveContext];
        NSLog(@"Switch Id is: %@",[name valueForKey:@"remindMeSwitchId"]);
        NSLog(@"Switch State is: %@",[name valueForKey:@"remindMeSwitchState"]);
    }

    [self dismissSelf];
}

- (IBAction)isAdedToCalendarValueChanged:(id)sender {

    if ([self.isAdedToCalendarOrNot isOn]) {
        self.isSwitchOnOrOf = YES;
    }
    else
    {
        self.isSwitchOnOrOf = NO;
    }
}
```

and for the exception that the app goes through:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSManagedObject setSwitchState:]: unrecognised selector sent to instance 0x7fb6f3411d20'

and for my xcdatamodel:

[image: xcdatamodel]

Comment: your entity name and attribute name are same.. and how did you create that class??? how did u create an entity name begin with lower case letter

Comment: i just try to renamed also same error

Comment: i tested by copying necessary codes and it works well..

Comment: that`s weird right ?

Comment: you have no attribute named switchState

Comment: How did you create entity class??

Comment: @ShebinKoshy what do you mean i just implemented the EntityClass in my question if you mean the way that i created it by making new File Cocoa touch class

Comment: SwitchStateEntity *h  = [ fetchedObjects firstObject];


NSLog(@"it should not be nil = %@",self.isSwitchOnOrOf);


[h setSwitchState:[NSNumber numberWithBool:self.isSwitchOnOrOf]];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SwitchStateEntity *h = [ fetchedObjects firstObject]; 
//try this code
NSLog(@"it should not be nil = %@",self.isSwitchOnOrOf); 

[h setSwitchState:[NSNumber numberWithBool:self.isSwitchOnOrOf]];
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update Code in Such File**

> SwitchStateEntity.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
@interface SwitchStateEntity : NSManagedObject
@property(strong,nonatomic) NSNumber *switchId;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSNumber *switchState;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSNumber *showReminderAlert;
@end
```

> SwitchStateEntity.m

```
#import "SwitchStateEntity.h"
@implementation SwitchStateEntity
@dynamic switchId;
@dynamic   switchState;
@dynamic showReminderAlert;
@end
```

**Also Update Entity name and class name in .xcdatamodeld file**

[image]

Comment: i just make what you did and i create new Entity inside the **xcdatamodel**  and the same error appear

Comment: whats your class name ? and entity name in model?

Comment: the class name is `SwitchStateEntity` and entity name in model is `SwitchStateEntity`

Comment: in SwitchStateEntity.h check interface define like  "@interface SwitchStateEntity : NSManagedObject"

Comment: already done and the error that`s really make me feel crazy:S

Comment: and if i NSLog(@"%@",fetchedObjects) i am able to get the object that stored initially the problem i think isn`t with **xcdatamodel** maybe it could be inside the EntityClass it self but i follow up your answer it drive me to the same situation **Unrecognised selector had been sent** and thats really annoying

Comment: have you remove completely from device and re-install app ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87338/discussion-between-gaurav-patel-and-zakaria-darwish).

Answer (score 0):

Do a `NSLog("%@", NSStringFromClass(h.class))` to see what kind of class the SwitchState object really is. Chances are you've incorrectly configured something in your Core Data Model file.

Also, seriously, all your class names should be UpperCaseWords...

Comment: take a look to my code i just update it the log give me "SwitchStateEntity"

Comment: how can some people test the code that i have and works fine and when i run it on my app it doesn`t work :S